# Is it possible to decrease CFBundleShortVersionString?

Tags: app-store, app-store-connect

I once submitted a version to the AppStore with a `CFBundleShortVersionString` in the format `yyyyMMddhhmmss`, e.g. `20151231123456`.

I would really love to change that now to a versioning scheme like e.g. 3.0.7. But that's not possible as Apple tells me that I have to increment the `CFBundleShortVersionString`. Is there any way to "reset" this?